# BigQuery Golang maxResults for Queries

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I would like to be able to specify maxResults when using the golang BigQuery library. It isn't clear how to do this, though. I don't see it as an option in the documentation, and I have browsed the source to try to find it but I only see some sporadic usage in seemingly functionality not related to queries. Is there a way to circumvent this issue?

Comment: There is maxResults parameter in [job.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#QueryRequest), however, it seems there is no related API in golang library

Comment: Yes, you can read the docs of that parameter in "list" section @zangw

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no implemented method in the SDK for that but after looking a bit, I found this one: [request](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#request)

You could try to execute an HTTP GET specifying the parameters (you can find an example of the use of parameters here: [query_parameters](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api#query_parameters))

Comment: Actually found this: https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#QueryConfig and more in particular this field: MaxBytesBilled int64 that could be useful. The doc says: "MaxBytesBilled limits the number of bytes billed for this job.  Queries that would exceed this limit will fail (without incurring a charge). If this field is less than 1, the project default will be used."

Answer (score 0):

By default the google API iterators manage page size for you.  The RowIterator returns a single row by default, backed internally by fetched pages that rely on the backend to select an appropriate size.

If however you want to specify a fixed max page size, you can use the [`google.golang.org/api/iterator`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/iterator) package to iterate by pages while specifying a specific size.  The size, in this case, corresponds to `maxResults` for BigQuery's query APIs.

See https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/wiki/Iterator-Guidelines for more general information about advanced iterator usage.

Here's a quick test to demonstrate with the RowIterator in bigquery.  It executes a query that returns a row for each day in October, and iterates by page:

```
func TestQueryPager(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()

    pageSize := 5

    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "your-project-id here")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    q := client.Query("SELECT * FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2022-10-01','2022-10-31', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as d")
    it, err := q.Read(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("query failure: %v", err)
    }
    pager := iterator.NewPager(it, pageSize, "")
    var fetchedPages int
    for {
        var rows [][]bigquery.Value
        nextToken, err := pager.NextPage(&rows)
        if err != nil {
            t.Fatalf("NextPage: %v", err)
        }
        fetchedPages = fetchedPages + 1
        if len(rows) > pageSize {
            t.Errorf("page size exceeded, got %d want %d", len(rows), pageSize)
        }
        t.Logf("(next token %s) page size: %d", nextToken, len(rows))
        if nextToken == "" {
            break
        }
    }

    wantPages := 7
    if fetchedPages != wantPages {
        t.Fatalf("fetched %d pages, wanted %d pages", fetchedPages, wantPages)
    }
}
```