# Pagination in the Go client for bigquery

Tags: go, google-bigquery

```
rawQuery := "SELECT num FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 25)) num;"
query := bqClient.Query(rawQuery)
it, err := query.Read(ctx)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // for brevity
}

for {
    var row myObject

    it.PageInfo().Token = token
    if err := it.Next(&row); err != nil {
        if errors.Is(err, iterator.Done) {
            break
    }
        return nil, "", err
    }

    nextToken = it.PageInfo().Token

    out = append(out, row)
    token = nextToken
    }
```

The documentation [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/issues/1126) reads like the value of `PageInfo().Token` should change every `N` (5 in this case) or, simply speaking, with every new page.

What happens, however, is the iterator just keeps appending rows to my slice (out) even though internally I can see that there is a field  called "rows" with a buffer of `N`.

What I want to achieve is reading rows from BQ in batches so that I can specify `MaxSize` and an empty string for `token` and then do some sort of cursor-based pagination with updating the value of `token`. For some reason, it doesn't work this way currently.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is, the library generates tokens that are lexicographically so similar that I got fooled.

To elaborate a bit more on the solution: in order to implement cursor-based pagination in BigQuery, we can do the following:

1. Start with an empty string for `token`, set `iterator.PageInfo().MaxSize = pageSize` (this is luckily configurable)
2. Iterate over `iterator.Next(&dst)` and append each `dst` to the final `sliceOfDst` as long as `len(sliceOfDst) < pageSize`
3. Get the new value of `iterator.PageInfo().Token` and start from (1) again ,this time after setting `iterator.PageInfo().Token to this value

This flow works pretty well for me and allows to process a large table in batches without using limit/offset based pagination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want page-based rather than row-based access, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74213385/212435 for an example.